# Visual Studio 2013 Sign in error

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-live

I randomly get the following error when clicking on "Sign in".  Sometimes it persists for hours.

I don't even have a chance to enter my login credentials.

> Identity providers could not be loaded from ACS.

Does anyone have an idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems to only occur when I am logged into the Administrator account in my browser.

When I login with my new user account, then I don't get the error.  I then still need to enter my credentials.